# Why when checkout Ant version 1.3 from SVN there is alot of errors in the Ant java project itself?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, svn, tags

I am trying to get an older version of ant project from SVN I checked out this url "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_13/" in eclipse to get ant version 1.3

I was surprised by large number of errors in the Ant java project itself, for example:

1. a class doesn't have the called method
2. it uses throw new Exception in a method but the method declaration doesn't have "throws AntException"
3. it uses enumeration variable called "enum" which is a reserved word
4. uses a class called project and i can't find this class

My question is: why are there such many errors in a project that is assumed to be working fine as it is committed on the SVN tag.

Comment: What does Ant have to do with Tomcat?

Comment: 1) *"a class doesn't have the called method"* What class? What method? Do you want us to guess? --- 2) What does `throw new Exception` have to do with `throws AntException`? It's not the same exception, so why would you expect the first to require the second? --- 3) `ANT_13` is from before `enum` became a reserved word (Java 5). You need to compile with an old (ancient) compiler (Java <= 4).

Comment: sorry for that i will edit this as i tried both tomcat and ant projects and have the same problem

Comment: If it the same, then it's likely all about version compatibility. Make sure you use versions that fit together. That includes the version of Java used for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Ant 1.3 is 16 years old and is designed to be built with Java 1.1. If you try and build it with a modern version of Java you are going to get all sorts of errors.